# How can I handle optional object input parameters when I want to ensure the existence (and validity) of that property

Tags: typescript

How can I best handle the case where I have a method with optional object member properties for the options object, but I still want to guarantee the existence of that property (with a default value) in the resulting instance? Do I have to define a different interface for `User.data` where `isNew` is not optional or is there a better way?

```
interface IUserData {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean | undefined;
  fullName: string;
  age: number;
  isNew?: boolean;
}
class User {
  public data: IUserData;
  constructor(data: IUserData) {
    this.data = Object.assign({
      isNew: true,
    }, data);
  }
}
```

With the code above, my goal is to ensure `typeof user.isNew === 'boolean'` or throw typing errors:

```
// Most common use case
const user = new User({ fullName: 'Joe', age: 45 });
typeof user.isNew === 'boolean'; // true

// A valid use case (in the code above) - this is what I want to prevent
const user = new User({ fullName: 'Joe', age: 45, isNew: undefined });
typeof user.isNew === 'boolean'; // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Any variable can be undefined in Javascript, and since it is optional even enabling `strictNullChecks` will not prevent your scenario. The best way to achieve the desired outcome it assign defaults after you copy `data` to the new instance.

```
class User {
    public data: IUserData;
    constructor(data: IUserData) {
        this.data = Object.assign({ }, data);
        assignDefaults(this.data, {
            isNew: true
        });

    }
}

function assignDefaults<T>(target: T, defaults: Partial<T>) :T {
    if (target == null) { // TypeError if undefined or null
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
    }
    for (var nextKey in defaults) {
        // Avoid bugs when hasOwnProperty is shadowed
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(defaults, nextKey)) {
            // Assign any values that are undefined in the target object,
            // either because they are not defined or because they were explicitly set to undefined
            if (target[nextKey] === void 0) {
                target[nextKey] = defaults[nextKey];
            }
        }
    }

    return target;
}
```